# hibernate merge throws EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Hibernate entity class representing a "device" table, which is linked to N deviceNetworks:

```
@Entity
    @Configurable  
    @Table(name = "device")
    public class Device implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;


        @Column(name = "device_name", nullable = false)
        private String deviceName;


        @OneToMany( cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
                    mappedBy = "device_network", 
                    targetEntity = DeviceNetwork.class, orphanRemoval = true)
        private final Set<DeviceNetwork> deviceNetworks = Sets.newHashSet();

        ......

        public Set<DeviceNetwork> getDeviceNetworks()
        {
            return deviceNetworks;
        }

        public void addDeviceNetwork(final DeviceNetwork deviceNetwork)
        {
            deviceNetworks.add(deviceNetwork);
        }

        public void removeDeviceNetwork(final DeviceNetwork deviceNetwork)
        {
            deviceNetworks.remove(deviceNetwork);
        }
    }
```

and the class representing "deviceNetwork":

```
@Entity
@Configurable
@Table(name = "device_network")
public class DeviceNetwork implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Device.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id", nullable=false)
    private Device device;
    @Column(name = "network_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String networkName;
    ......
}
```

I have a transaction that inserted a new device and a new linked deviceNetwork into DB, then I started with a new tranaction:

1. retrieve the newly inserted device by its id;
2. add a new network;
3. update the device;

I use EntityManager to accomplish this:

```
@Transactional
public void addNetworkToDevice(long deviceId, DeviceNetwork deviceNetwork)
{
    Device device = entityManager.get(deviceId); 

    device.addDeviceNetwork(deviceNetwork);

    entityManager.merge(device);
}
```

This causes the following exceptions:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: 
Unable to find com.xxx.domain.DeviceNetwork with id 170; 
nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find com.xxx.domain.DeviceNetwork with id 170
```

The id=170 is supposed to be the DeviceNetwork to be inserted. It appears that the merge() would try to retrieve the 
about-to-inserted deviceNetwork by its auto-generated id, but failed to do so because it hasn't been inserted.

An interesting thing is that if I insert a new device and 2 new linked deviceNetworks in the same transaction, it works fine:

```
@Transactional
public void addDevice(Device device, DeviceNetwork deviceNetwork1, DeviceNetwork deviceNetwork2)
{
    Device deviceInDB = entityManager.get(device.getDeviceId());
    if deviceInDB == null)
    {
        entityManager.persist(device);
        deviceInDB = entityManager.get(device.getDeviceId());
    }

    deviceInDB.addDeviceNetwork(deviceNetwork1);
    deviceInDB.addDeviceNetwork(deviceNetwork2);

    entityManager.merge(deviceInDB);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added the class mapping in hibernate config?

Comment: It looks like the data isn't actually being committed to the database. You second code example will work because the call to get() will read the object from the Hibernate session cache, not from the db. What transaction set up are you using? You're not accidentally using a test runner that rolls back transactions or something like that?

Comment: The transaction is configured as: <bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />. 
    </bean>

Comment: There is no rollback or anything. Can I ask you a more fundamental question: what exactly happens in merge()? is it (1)insert into device_network; (2)query device_network to get the newly inserted row by auto-generated id; (3)update the row with device id and update it? I just don't understand why it complains the new row does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Check if database user mentioned in the project has access to the table device_network